# Convert LPCOLESTR to BSTR?

Tags: c++, bstr

Any ideas on how to make a BSTR out of an LPCOLESTR? Silly thing to get hung up on..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `LPCOLESTR` is just a `const wchar_t*`, so you can use [`SysAllocString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221458.aspx) to create a `BSTR`:

```
LPCOLESTR olestr = ...;
BSTR bstr = SysAllocString(olestr);
```

Be sure to call [`SysFreeString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221481.aspx) when you're done with your `BSTR`.  See also the [MSDN documentation on `BSTR`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221069.aspx)

Comment: Note that OLECHAR == wchar_t is true only on a Wintel platform. Not sure what the other platforms were, but it was funny stuff, and on them BSTR is probably just a char *, too,  so your answer is correct for all practical purposes  ;)

Answer (score 3):

The difference between BSTR and LPCOLESTR is that BSTR has the length of the string prefixed before the string, LPCOLESTR hasn't.

A BSTR doesn't necessarily have an ending \0 marking end of string, since the length of the string is prefixed, to convert I usually use the class CComBSTR (atlcomcli.h), the ctor takes either BSTR or LPCOLESTR as argument and there is a member BSTR() to get the BSTR representation:

```
CComBSTR b( yourolestring )
// b.BSTR()
```

CComBSTR will handle the allocating/freeing so no risk of memory leak.